# Do you know why the city names are appearing twice?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have an input search using autocomplete plugin that shows the conference names and cities where the conferences will happen. When the user types 1 word it appears the results in the autocomplete.

But there is an issue, for example, if there are in the conferences table two conferences that have the city column equal, example "Newcastle" in the autocomplete input appears "Newcastle" twice. But it should appear only one time. Do you know where is the issue?

AutoCompleteController:

```
class AutocompleteController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
    return view('autocomplete.index');
    }

    public function search(Request $request){
        $search = $request->term;
        $conferences = Conference::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

        $cities = Conference::where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();


        //dd($cities); 
        $data= [];
        foreach ($conferences as $key => $value){
            $data[] = ['category'=> 'Conferences', 'value' => $value->name, 'url' => 'conference/'.$value->id.'/'.$value->slug];
        }

        foreach ($cities as $key => $value){
            $data[] = ['category'=> 'Cities', 'value' => $value->city, 'url' => 'conferences/where/city/'.$value->city];
        }
        return response($data);
    }
}
```

Autocomplete Jquery:

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
_create: function() {
    this._super();
    this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
    },
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var that = this,
    currentCategory = "";
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        var li;
        if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
            ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category bg bg-light-gray2 h6 font-weight-bold text-heading-blue'>"
            + item.category + "</li>" );
            currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
        if ( item.category ) {
        li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
        }
    });
    }
});

$("#search").catcomplete({
    source: "{{ URL::to('autocomplete-search') }}",
    select: function(event, ui) {
    window.location.href = ui.item.url;
}
```

When "New" is typed dd($cities) shows:

```
Collection {#274
#items: array:2 [
0 => Conference {#275
#fillable: array:18 [
0 => "name"
5 => "city"
...
]
#dates: array:2 [
0 => "start_date"
1 => "end_date"
]
#appends: array:1 [
0 => "price_range"
]
#connection: "mysql"
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:23 [
"id" => 1
"name" => "conf1"
"city" => "Newcastle"
]
#original: array:23 [
"id" => 1
"name" => "conf1"
"city" => "Newcastle"
]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dateFormat: null
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#guarded: array:1 [
0 => "*"
]
}
1 => Conference {#276
#fillable: array:18 [
0 => "name"
5 => "city"
...
]
#dates: array:2 [
0 => "start_date"
1 => "end_date"
]
#appends: array:1 [
0 => "price_range"
]
#connection: "mysql"
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:23 [
"id" => 2
"name" => "conf2"
"city" => "Newcastle"
...
]
#original: array:23 [
"id" => 2
"name" => "conf2"
"city" => "Newcastle"
...
]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dateFormat: null
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#guarded: array:1 [
0 => "*"
]
}
]
}
```

And it shows without the dd($cities):

```
[{category: "Cities", value: "Newcastle", url: "conferences/where/city/Newcastle"},…]
0
:
{category: "Cities", value: "Newcastle", url: "conferences/where/city/Newcastle"}
1
:
{category: "Cities", value: "Newcastle", url: "conferences/where/city/Newcastle"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ˋdistinct()` like this:

```
$cities = Conference::where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')-> distinct()->get(['city']);
```